# __enter__ error when printing matrix with "with" statement

Tags: python, numpy

I run this:

```
import numpy as np
import sys
temp = np.array([[10, 20], [30, 40]])
with np.set_printoptions(threshold=10):
    print(temp)
```

And it give me `AttributeError: __enter__`
What should I do?

Comment: What makes you think you can use `set_printoptions` in a with block?

Comment: The context manager is called [`numpy.printoptions`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.17/reference/generated/numpy.printoptions.html).  See @PythonNoob's answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this:

```
>>> with np.printoptions(threshold=10):
...     print(temp)
...
[[10 20]
 [30 40]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the options via:

```
np.set_printoptions(threshold=10)
```

The `with` keyword is used in a different context, e.g., to open files:

```
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    ...
```